# JQuery get the nearest Sibling input

Tags: jquery

Here's my a gist of my document structure

```
    <input type="number" name="checkOutItemList[${status.index}].quantity"
class="item-Quantity form-control" placeholder="0"
value="${item.quantity}">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-2 col-xs-9">
    <label class="control-label" for="subtotal">
        Subtotal
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="subtotal form-control" id="subtotal" value="${item.srp * item.quantity}" placeholder="0.00" disabled>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
$(document).on('change', ".item-Quantity", function(e) {
    console.log($(this).closest('input .subtotal').val())
});
```

However it only returns an undefined

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$(document).on('change', ".item-Quantity", function(e) {
   console.log($(this).parent().next().find('input.subtotal').val());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upcht1wz/)**

Comment: Why parent and then next?

Comment: It is the sibling of the parent div you are looking for. Also if the field is not dynamic, you can do `$(".item-Quantity").on("change",...` instead of `$(document).on('change', ".item-Quantity",`

Comment: the input you are looking for is lying inside the next sibling div of current parent div.

Comment: The fields are dynamic

Comment: @user962206: that should not be a problem as event is delegated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :Use `closest()` to get parent `div` then use `.next()` to get next `div` to parent `div`, after that use `.find()` to get subtotal input. Make sure that there is not space between `input` and `.subtotal` as you are finding input with `class="subtotal"`.

```
$(document).on('change', ".item-Quantity", function(e) {
    console.log($(this).closest('div').next('.form-group').find('input.subtotal').val())
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why make it so complicated just:

```
$(document).on('change', ".item-Quantity", function(e) {
    console.log($(this).closest('input').val());
});
```

> Note: In case of using `.class` selector there is always a chance that array of object will be returned. `#id` selector always returns one item.

Working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/urahara/2cpcuogo/

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('input.subtotal').val()
```